# Monitor POST requests to server in localhost

Tags: node.js

I wrote a simple route where my React app makes POST requests to and I would like to monitor those requests while in dev mode.

Despite I am logging it to console my terminal is not showing it, because I am running the app from React. How can I monitor post requests in my localhost?

```
app.post("/api/product_ids", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ BODY: req.query });
  console.log(res.query);
});
```

Comment: I think you need to console.log before you res.send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to console.log before you res.send. Make sure you are grabbing the right values too.

```
app.post("/api/product_ids", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(...);
});
```

Comment: I've tested with req.body but it does not work, it only works with res.query

Comment: Ah well usually when you make a post request you are attaching data to the 'body' parameter. I think you can call it whatever you want so it's possible you called it 'query' instead of 'body'.